# How to get Google Drive items containing a slash in the title

Tags: google-drive-api

How can I get all folders and files which contains a **/** in the title? When I use the API with `q: 'title contains "/"'` I get all files. Same with Google App Scripts. It seems it is ignored by the API. When I loop through all the folders and files to look with regular expression it will work but it is very expensive.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code or sample that you are utilizing to make searches.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. How to accept answer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

**The Drive API Search Parameters limitations**

I ran a couple of test with different types of query parameters based on the official documentation. Utilizing the option of `fulltext contains`

It would throw all files in general. It seems that the query just uses the "/" character as a general character without properly making the searches. It does not match the file name it generally takes any "/" that is available in the Drive API information that is being pulled from `files.list`

It would be an excellent idea to make a feature request or provide insight about this limitation for a documentation update on why, similar to the discussions and reports being done when it comes to the query parameters:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149522397

You should be able to provide a sample code and samples, to the search results similar to the ones provided when utilizing the try it API:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list

Mainly because it seems that is not possible with any of the parameters available and there is no clear confirmation if those special characters are used for other purposes.

References:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues (You can send the issue or bug information here)